# Postgres Role required to grant CONNECT on a specific database

Tags: postgresql, user-management, database-administration, psql

I am trying to GRANT CONNECT on a DATABASE to a user as a schema owner in that database.

The schema owner is not a superuser.

Do I need to be the owner of a database to execute

```
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE DBXXX TO USER_YYY; ??
```

What role should a user be granted other than superuser to allow it to grant connect?

Comment: If you're using psql you can do `\h grant` to see the full syntax for grant.

Comment: Yeah, the with grant option was not super clear to me in the docs but it made sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were given `CONNECT WITH GRANT OPTION` you can then grant connect to others.

If you were not given connect with grant option, you cannot grant it, you will need a superuser to grant you `CONNECT GRANT OPTION`, or to grant connect to the new user.

A superuser (or database owner) would use this command to grant grant option for connect:

```
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE database_name TO your_username WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

As a schema owner you can grant usage on your schema to others.